# Video as a background in a div tag HTML

Tags: html, video

Im trying to get a video as a background in a div tap like (plated.com) here is what i got i cannot get the video inside the div, it keeps going full screen.

```
             <section>
                <div id="video-container">
                    <video id="bgvid" autoplay poster="images/logo.png" muted>
                        <source src="videos/allyouneed.mp4" type="video/mp4"/>
                    </video>
                </div>
            </section>



       #video-container{
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-height: 500px; 
    border: 2px green solid;


}
video#bgvid{
    position: relative;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    z-index: -100;
```

Comment: You might want to check that your css is correct, the `video#bgvid` might be missing a close tag.